# Best Way to Reduce Bandwidth Usage with Magento eCommerce

Tags: magento, bandwidth

Currently I am working on a website that is using the Magento eCommerce platform.

Although the website has only seen about 1,000 visitors over a 30 day period, it is using over 70 GB of bandwidth. The website has Cache enabled to help reduce the amount of resources it takes to load each page, but it does not appear to be helping. I was hoping to find some pro tips on how to reduce the amount of bandwidth usage to avoid costly overage fee's with the hosting provider.

The website is http://fantasyfootballdraftboard.net if you would like to review the site. The primary purpose of the website is to sell fantasy football draft boards online, so I would prefer not to remove the large image on the home page. I've used Pingdom speed test, and it claims the site only uses roughly 2.5 MB of bandwidth to load each page. After a pretty in-depth analysis of Google Analytics, Page Views, and the amount of bandwidth it takes to load each page (2.5 mb according to Pingdom), the numbers just do not add up.

Does anybody have any suggestions or ideas for me? Does Magento use a lot more resources and bandwidth than other eCommerce websites?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I ran your site through webpagetest and there are a few recommendations from there. You should certainly compress your transfer. Personally, I would recommend you avoid png files for images unless you really need them (eg for see through effects). Jpegs are much more efficient and compressed.

Go through webpagetest and I'd bet you could knock off at least a megabyte!

Answer (score 0):

I am check your website, but find any problom.

and bandwith is no relation magento system.

maybe your image are other site used or stolen ftp password by cracker,

HTTP_REFERER check in apache config (or .haccess file )

http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4515652.htm